# Installing Microsoft Z3 on macbook M1

Tags: installation, microsoft, macos-monterey

I recently changed my old macbook air and purchased a macbook M1. I would like to install on it [Microsoft Research z3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/z3-3/). Is it possible? Does it work on M1?

I went to github [link](https://github.com/z3prover/z3) where there is everything one needs to install z3. Unfortunately I have to admit that I am not IT savvy at all, *and going to that link I don't even know where to begin.*

> Is there anyone so kind to explain to me how to install z3 in little steps like I am really dumb and know very little about IT technical stuff?

Thanks for your kind help. Feel free to edit the tags as you see appropriate.

Comment: The project is open source.  However, it's C++, so you would have to specifically target ARM64, if that compile is successful would be up to you to determine.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to do that...

Comment: Sounds like you have your answer.  The project is not automatically targeting ARM64 at this time.  You would have to do that yourself and resolve any other dependencies that might exist.